# What is the best use of provided SQL Database table in Windows Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, azure, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

I have been experimenting with Windows Azure Mobile Services. I am impressed that it creates a table for me and a database connection along with projects in various platforms. I wish the data were Windows Azure Storage however, because SQL Database can be expensive.

My thought is, since it is already provided, it makes sense to use it to store account information. Then I can use Azure Storage for frequently changing data. What minimal information should be necessary for such a use?
Here is a possible table design.

- unique_id: GUID
- email_address : varchar
- oath_provider_choice : varchar
- oath_yahoo : varchar
- oath_google : varchar
- oath_microsoft : varchar

Does this make sense or is it too much?

Comment: If you are just going to use the authentication, let the default mobile services handle it, like in this article: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet . If you are worried about expense, you might just roll your own auth system using Azure Table Storage.

Comment: I agree with Joey - using the built-in functionality is much easier. If you need more info here is another article:  http://chrisrisner.com/Authentication-with-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

Comment: Great links guys. Should I just remove that SQL Database table then, if I want to use Azure Storage?

Comment: I would - as it will only add confusion if left.

Comment: It is a requirement that any class used in WAMS includes an Id property with a type of integer that is used to uniquely identify the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Azure Table Storage from Mobile Services using the Azure Module.  I have a pretty extensive sample here (http://chrisrisner.com/Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage) which shows how to insert / update / delete / read tables and rows from Mobile Services Table Scripts (effectively bypassing using the SQL database).  It also shows how you can use blob storage.  Now that Mobile Services has Custom API, it might make more sense to use that as opposed to the table scripts.  You can also communicate directly with table storage (warning: this would require having the account name / key in your client app).  As pointed out in the comments, currently each table in Mobile Services generates an ID column which has to be a bigint.